# Why will a register not be available for a variable in C?

Tags: c, operating-system

In C language, if we have declared a register variable, it will be treated as an auto variable if the register is not available.

However, for every process switch, the contents of the register are pushed onto the stack. So when a C code is executing, the registers are free from use by other programs.

Then why is it that a register is sometimes not available for my variable?

Comment: `register` is only **an optimization hint**, though it also forbids taking the address of any such variable. Modern compilers disregard it completely, because they are better at omptimizing than you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`register` is only **an (obsolete) optimization hint**:

- You (the programmer) expect the variable is heavily used.
- You are forbidden from taking the variables address.
- Otherwise equivalent to `auto` storage class.

Modern compilers disregard that hint completely.

That allows them to better allocate the - possibly scarce - registers and produce better code.

> #### 6.5.3.2 Address and indirection operators § 1
>
> Constraints
>   1 The operand of the unary `&` operator shall be either a function designator, the result of a
>   `[]` or unary `*` operator, or an lvalue that designates an object that is not a bit-field and is
>   not declared with the `register` storage-class specifier.

> #### 6.7.1 Storage-class specifiers § 6
>
> 6 A declaration of an identifier for an object with storage-class specifier `register`
>   suggests that access to the object be as fast as possible. The extent to which such
>   suggestions are effective is implementation-defined.121)

Comment: I'm not sure if there aren't cases where this is a useful hint for the compiler: It tells it, that no pointer (to compatible type or `char`/`void`) will alias the denoted object and this could be useful for caching.

Comment: @mafso No, the compiler has the full code of that function and can easily deduce that local fact.

Comment: OK, convinced, `register` is virtually useless (except the compiler is bad at optimization, or you write very strange programs (using `scanf("%p", ...)` or the like)…

Answer (score 2):

No.  When your program is not executing, it has no need of registers -- it's not executing.  Any register variables will be pushed to the stack so that other programs can use the registers.

The reason why registers may not be available is that there are only a small number of registers available.  If all of them are in use by something more important, then your "register" variable will be treated as any other variable.

Comment: I want to know what exactly are the registers then used for (apart from the register variables I declare) when it is executing my code?

Comment: @user2684198: It sounds like you don't really want to program in C. You should program in assembler directly instead, then you'll have full control over everything.

Comment: @user2684198: They're used for temporary values, cached copies of variables, pointers, etc.  Disassemble your program if you want to see exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

different processors have different numbers of registers, so the number of variables that can be accommodated may vary.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you declare 40 variables with the `register` keyword. Do you really think all of them will get a register?

Comment: I know it wont. But what if I declared only one? Will it definitely get a register? If not, why so?

Comment: @KerrekSB, there are (dead) exceptions. But let's say 500 then.

Comment: @user2684198, as others have said, it's only a hint. In many cases, the compiler will use registers for variables even though your didn't specify `register`. So it might completely ignore your hint and decide to use registers for other variables that it deems more worthy. Usually, the compiler is smarter (or at least more aware of the specifics of each architecture) that you might be.

Answer (score 0):

Most (possibly all) modern compilers will simply ignore the `register` keyword in so far as actually assigning to a register is concerned - the compiler has greater *expertise* in the target processor instruction set that most programmers and will  do a better job of optimisation than could be achieved by human intervention.  Such *second guessing* can even impede compiler optimisation.

Many processors such as x86 do not have a large orthogonal register set necessary to make register allocation practical or efficient.  Moreover registers are used for intermediate operations in implementation of high-level languages - they cannot all be available for explicit variable storage.

That said the `register` keyword does have the effect of preventing the address of a variable being taken, and this information (that fact that you will not take the variables address), can be used by the compiler to inform optimisation, but I doubt that that potential is realised in practice, or is significant in most cases if it is. See [A common misconception: the `register` keyword](http://gustedt.wordpress.com/2010/08/17/a-common-misconsception-the-register-keyword/)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from inavailability of registers, there are n number of reason for a compiler, which doesn't gives register to a user variable declared with register storage class. Some of them are listed below.

- If compiler wants to perform its own optimization, this may omit all user optimization suggestions.
- If compiler thought like the variable is not really worth to keep in register.
- If compiler like keeping that user variable may impact performance.